# How to extract date from a string if the string has date that in are in different date format

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of multiple sting which contains data in format like "Dated 23rd January 2018" or "Dt. 23.11.2018" and the date is mostly at the end of the string, can someone show me how can I extract the date using python or any other method

Answer (score 0):

```
    from datetime import datetime

    allYears = ['y','-y','Y']
    allMonths = ['b','B','m','-m']
    allDays = ['d','-d']


    def checkIfDate(dateRecieved):
        for year in allYears:
        for month in allMonths:
        for day in allDays:
            for separator in [['/', ' '], ['/', '.'], [' ', '/'], ['.', '/'], [' ', '.'], ['.', ' '], ['.', '.'], ['/', '/'], [' ', ' '],['rd', '/'], ['rd', '.'], ['rd', ' '], ['th', '/'], ['th', '.'], ['th', ' ']]:
                try:
                    if separator[0] in ['th', 'rd']:
                        date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(dateRecieved, f'%{day}{separator[0]} %{month}{separator[1]}%{year}')
                    else:
                        date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(dateRecieved, f'%{day}{separator[0]}%{month}{separator[1]}%{year}')
                except:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(year, month, day, separator)
                    print(date_time_obj)

    date_time_str = '18rd Dec.2019'

    checkIfDate(date_time_str)
```

This code works if the dates are of the form :

- **18/Dec.2019**
- **18.Dec/2019**
- **18rd Dec 2019**
- **18th Dec/2019**

But this will not work if you have spaces around separators like **/** and **.** Such as :-

- **18 / Dec.2019**
- **18/Dec . 2019**
- **18 . Dec / 2019**

Sorry if this is not what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks for the answer it does work but not for my purpose, I want to extract the date from a title for e.g. 'Notification regarding the .........Dated 4th January 2020'